# LibreOffice Math is Invisible!

Tags: libreoffice

I wanted to try out the LibreOffice Math. When I checked the Ubuntu Software, it was shown as it was already installed, so I tried to search for it in the menu and it was not shown, but the other LibreOffice products were present in the menu. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it using the Ubuntu Software and also using the Terminal but it still was not visible. Is  there any solution for this?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If you start just `libreoffice`, is there an option for Create: Math Formula at the left of the main window?

Comment: Yes when I type libreoffice in the terminal(not found in the menu) it opens up and Math Formula is there at the left of the main window.

Comment: OK, so this is just an issue with where the menu item is placed. Seems like I've seen it under Education or somewhere weird like that before. You could try `grep Categories /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop` to see where it got placed.

Comment: So what should I do to get it in the menu?

Comment: I don't know how the menus work on the default Ubuntu desktop.  Suggest editing your question to clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: The menu and Show Application(square with 3x3 dots)? Am I right?

Comment: I don't use that desktop, so I don't know the answer to that. I use LXDE.

Comment: On XFCE (Xubuntu 18.04) I have the same as @OrganicMarble - under Eductation while the rest of LibreOffice is under Office

Comment: When installing it **from libreoffice.org**, Math is automatically displayed in menus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the author is new to Linux or not used to computers, a more detailed answer may be needed.

1. Go to "Other Locations", then click on "Computer". When an address starts with `/`, you can start following it from here.

   [image]
2. Click on the `usr` folder

   [image]
3. You'll now find yourself in `/usr/`. Continue this way until you reach the applications folder at `/usr/share/applications/`. Here, right-click on `libreoffice-math.desktop`, then click on "Copy". This will copy the file.

   [image]
4. Now go to "Home". This is where your files are. The address of `.local` is `~/.local`, with `~/` meaning the home folder. Yours will probably have less cluster being a new installation.

   [image]

   However, if we look around, you will find no `.local` folder. This is normal, folders starting with `.` are hidden to avoid the mess. Click on "Show Hidden Folders" to show them. Many folders have appeared including `.local`.

   [image]
5. Go to `.local/share/applications`, here right-click and click on "Paste".

   [image]

   Double-click the file `libreoffice-math.desktop` and a text editor should open. Find the line `NotShowIn=GNOME;` and replace it with `#NotShowIn=GNOME;`.

   [image]
6. Press the save button. Now you should find LibreOffice Math.

   [image]

Comment: thnx a lot it was really helpful and FYI I am not new to "unused to computers" I have a really good knowledge about Windows 7 & 10 OS I am just really new to Linux and I don't understand the directories.

Comment: @LohithRaj yeah wasn't really able to judge your level, so I chose to do instructions that anybody even somebody very unused to computers can follow. It's hard to know how simple to go although in retrospective explaining how to copy and paste was probably too extreme, people who don't know how to do that are rare nowadays. It was not meant as disrespect.

Comment: Wow, that's complicated.  When installing it from libreoffice.org, Math is automatically displayed in menus.

Comment: @RonJohn it could be an ubuntu customization.

Comment: @user253751 I'm sure it is... :)

Answer (score 18):

Math is a component of LibreOffice that serves to create mathematical formulas. It is usually used from within another LibreOffice document. Because it is rarely used on its own, Ubuntu developers opted not to show it by default in the Application menu.

If you wish, you can reveal it in your own application menu as follows:

- Copy the `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop` file to the folder `.local/share/applications`. `.local` is a hidden folder in your home folder.
- Open the copy, `~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop`, in a text editor.
- Find the line `NotShowIn=GNOME;`. Put a comment character, `#`, in front of the line or delete the line.
- Save the file and close the editor.

After saving that file, the item for Math will, after a short while, be shown in your menu.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I am really new to linux(joined 3 days ago) and also I didn't anything you just wrote. If it's only possible can you simplify it to noob terms, to terms that windows user can understand. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Lohith It seems fine to me, and I do technical support for noobs for a living :p What is unclear?

Comment: @wjandrea can you explain me the answer in a much more simpler way?

Comment: @LohithRaj The instructions are to copy a specific file and edit it. Which part is unclear?

Comment: @gronostaj nothing at all!!!

Comment: The "fully automated way" is to open a terminal and paste `grep -v '^NotShowIn' /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop > ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

And, ensure that "Hide from menus" is 'off'. If it is 'on' then 'off' it.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you wondering how to perform the actions from [vanadium's reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299068/1233902) in Ubuntu:

1. Open Terminal with `Ctrl + Alt + T` or open the Start Menu and type
   "Terminal".
2. Copy this command: `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop .local/share/applications/`
3. Now go to Terminal and paste it using: `Ctrl + Shift + V`, and press Enter.
4. Enter your password and press Enter.
5. After the file copies into the specified directory, copy the next command into the Terminal and Enter it in: `sudo nano ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop`
6. With the file open in **nano**, use the Find function using `Ctrl + W`; type "GNOME" and press Enter.
7. Your Terminal cursor should be blinking on this line: `NotShowIn=GNOME;`.
8. While still in **nano**, press `Ctrl + A` to skip the cursor to the beginning of the line.
9. With the Terminal cursor at the beginning of the line, press `Shift + 3' to add a "#". This will *comment-out* the line. It should look like this:

> #NotShowIn=GNOME;

10. While on the Terminal window, inside of **nano**, press `Ctrl + S`
    to save the file.
11. Now press `Ctrl + X` to close **nano**.

Now you should be able to press your Windows key to open the App Drawer, type in "math" and see LibreOffice Math as a result as seen here:

[LibreOffice Math in Ubuntu Start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv6Gn.png)

Comment: You could just edit Vanadium's answer rather than creating an almost duplicate answer.

Comment: I figured both could occupy the same space to help different levels of experience, but I see how editing Vanadium's answer could save space; thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your terminal and execute the following command:

```
grep -v NotShowIn=GNOME /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop >  ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop
```

As an explanation it shows all text but the one that has the line "NotShowIn=GNOME" and then places all that into the ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-math.desktop file.

This idea is originally from [Matteo Italia](https://askubuntu.com/users/208527/matteo-italia) as a comment to a previous response, but I believe this actually deserves an answer instead of a comment.